# Call or text back to a private number

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

I'm using `BroadcastReceiver` to determine that calls or messages are from private numbers.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Bundle onReceiveBundle = intent.getExtras();

    String phoneNumber = onReceiveBundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
}
```

The `phoneNumber` returns negative numbers which cannot be called or replied back. Without the need to decode it, is it possible to reply or call back to a private number? If not, how can I decode it?

Comment: Can you post few sample phone numbers which returns negative numbers?

Comment: @Rinav any number set as private when dialing will reproduce this. It all depends on settings in the dialer app (at least on my device, that's where you'd set it as a private number). So supplying specific numbers isn't possible, because they're not private unless the call is "sent" as private

Comment: you can't decode private numbers, the service provider doesn't give the device this information for privacy reasons

Comment: @marmor I read somewhere that there is an app that is doing but it was not my intention at the moment. If I can't return a call or text, should I just do not allow it?

Comment: `should I just do not allow it` - you mean to block private calls? yeah, you can do that in an app, search SO for this